# Creating sub-numbered lists in OneNote

Tags: microsoft-onenote, microsoft-onenote-2010, numbering

Is it possible to create numbered lists in OneNote that have subsections?

Ex:
1. Section
1.1 Subsection
1.2 Another Subsection

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was able to figure this out for you.

Click `Home`

[image]

Click the little arrow to choose numbering style

[image]

Click `Customize numbering`

[image]

Choose the Sequence style and the Format

[image]

Type your content then press `Enter` then `Backspace` then `Tab`

[image]

Choose format for next section

[image]

To create a sub-section to the sub-section, press `Enter` then `Backspace` then `Tab`

[image]

Continue the sub-section.

[image]

To go back to the previous section, from the content line press `Enter` then `Backspace` twice

[image]

Continue that section then to return to previous section, from content line press `Enter` then `Backspace` twice

[image]

To go back to first section press `Backspace` twice again

[image]

Continue your section from there

[image]

As far as changing the numbering to 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, etc. I don't think you can. You have to choose from the predefined formats. You can choose what number to start at though from the last option on the `Customize numbering` window. I tried changing it to 1.1 and 1.2 but it doesn't stick

[image]

Comment: you can do the same process for as many subsections as you want. so you can do 1. main I. subsection A. sub-subsection. as much as you like. it will keep track of all of the numbers as you backspace to continue in a previous section.

Comment: I think I understand what you're saying, but I can't seem to recreate it.

Comment: How do I choose my numbering style, then, to create 1.1, 1.2, 1.3 etc?

Comment: I changed my answer above to make it easier for you to understand.

Comment: Thanks :) I already understood the lists, but I was looking for a way to get the 1.1, 1.2 style sublists. I guess there isn't really a way yet then

Comment: Yeah I haven't come across a way to do a custom format. On the bright side though between the sequence and format options provided there are plenty to choose from.

Comment: This shouldn't be an accepted answer, unless it says at the top that it can't be done.  I followed all the steps and found out the very end, you couldn't do what the OP asked.

Answer (score 3):

As of 2021, it cannot be done. One can customize the format of the individual levels, but including numbers from higher levels (like 2.1.3.4) is not possible to do in OneNote on any platform.